# How To Stop React Rerendering My Page With Dynamic Imports?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

For my homepage I am trying to use loadable components with an intersection observer.  When my redux store updates, the entire page gets rerendered.  How can I avoid this?

```
import React from "react"
import loadable from "@loadable/component"
import { useSelector } from "react-redux"

const Index = () => {
const intersectState = useSelector(state => state.intersectState)

const BannerProducts = loadable(() =>
    import("../components/bannerProducts/bannerProducts")
  )
const SellingBulletPoints = loadable(() =>
    import("../components/sellingBulletPoints/sellingBulletPoints")
  )

const Category = intersectState.categoryComponent &&
loadable(() => import("../components/category/category"))

return (
<>
  <BannerProducts />
  <SellingBulletPoints />
  {intersectState.categoryComponent && <Category />}
</>
 )
}

export default Index
```

Comment: Use `useMemo` or use`useCallBack` to stop the rerendering.I think this link will help you https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback or if you want to see official documentation please visit this also.https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that React incorrectly thinks the components are a new component every time the component re-renders.

This happens because your components are getting re-defined every render.

If you move these lazy loading component definitions outside of the render function, then it should work fine.

```
const BannerProducts = loadable(() =>
    import("../components/bannerProducts/bannerProducts")
  )
const SellingBulletPoints = loadable(() =>
    import("../components/sellingBulletPoints/sellingBulletPoints")
  )

const Category = loadable(() => import("../components/category/category"))
```

---

Here's how it works:

The `loadable(()=>import('./component'))` call only creates a wrapper component that when rendered will suspend (or just render null) until the full code is in the browser and ready to run. Until that component is rendered, the code split code *doesn't* get loaded in the browser.

So, by re-creating the lazy-loading wrapper component, you are doing nothing but adding extra cycles. In fact, you are destroying what React uses to determining if it's the same element being rendered (i.e. `Component===Component`). So for every time the parent element re-renders, your lazy-loading wrapper component is getting recreated, which causes it to unmount/remount.

Luckily, the lazy loading is sufficiently optimized so that it only loads the same chunk one time - when the lazy-loaded component is first rendered (hence the `import('./component')` line).

In order to get this point across of *how* this functions and *why* your component is getting remounted, I set up a code sandbox with 3 components all with the same code (albeit with different names and strings).

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
console.log("CodeSplit Code loaded!");
export default function CodeSplit() {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`CodeSplit Mounted`);
    return () => {
      console.log(`CodeSplit Unmounted`);
    };
  }, []);
  return <div>CodeSplit</div>;
}
```

If you run the codesandbox, the three components are:
`NormalCode` - Code rendered synchronously as part of the base bundle. The `NormalCode Code Loaded` message is logged as the code runs when the main bundle is loaded.

`CodeSplit` - Code is lazy loaded using `loadable` but in the correct way of using it. The `CodeSplit Code Loaded` message is logged as soon as the `show splits` button is clicked. This happens because that's the first time the `CodeSplit` lazy loaded component is rendered even though `<CodeSplit />` is in the call. With this, when it's rendered and you type into the input, there's no further `CodeSplit Mounted` and `CodeSplit Unmounted` messages.

`CodeSplitGoofed` - Code is lazy loaded using `loadable`, but the lazy loading component is being generated in the `App` component's render. The behavior of this is the same as `CodeSplit` for the lazy loading aspects, *but* when you type into the input, you can see from the `CodeSplitGoofed Mounted` and `CodeSplitGoofed Unmounted` console logs that this component is getting unmounted and remounted with every time the `App` component re-renders. The reason for that is as above - React can't know that this is the same component as it was before.

https://codesandbox.io/s/so-stop-react-rerendering-page-with-dynamic-import-mch7g?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I actually typed it wrong... See above.  The problem is intersectState.categoryComponent also needs to be in the component definitions.  I want to say... if the state in redux is updated... go fetch the JS for that component and render it without refreshing the whole page.

Comment: There's no difference in functionality of what I suggested compared to what you edited.
Unless you are dynamically importing a different `Category` component from a different path (in which case good luck with webpack...), let the lazy loading components do its thing. You don't need to re-create the lazy loaded component every time; just dynamically render the component. Recreating the component will cause React to think its a completely different component every time. So it'll lose all internal state as the previous one will be unmounted and the new will be mounted.

Comment: The difference is that const Category = intersectState.categoryComponent &&
loadable(() => import("../components/category/category")) only loads the javascript if the redux state says it hasn't been loaded yet by an intersection observer.  If I remove the state check then it will load the JS on page load even if the user does not scroll to the component.  I was just trying to chunk out the JS and only load it when the user hits that component.

Comment: @JasonBiondo I updated my answer with an example and plenty of description to help you understand how lazy loading works.